# Update locals from inside a function

Tags: python

I would like to write a function which receives a local namespace dictionary and update it. Something like this:

```
def UpdateLocals(local_dict):
  d = {'a':10, 'b':20, 'c':30}
  local_dict.update(d)
```

When I call this function from the interactive python shell it works all right, like this:

```
a = 1
UpdateLocals(locals())

# prints 20
print a
```

However, when I call `UpdateLocals` from inside a function, it doesn't do what I expect:

```
def TestUpdateLocals():
  a = 1
  UpdateLocals(locals())
  print a

# prints 1
TestUpdateLocals()
```

How can I make the second case work like the first?

UPDATE:

Aswin's explanation makes sense and is very helpful to me. However I still want a mechanism to update the local variables. Before I figure out a less ugly approach, I'm going to do the following:

```
def LoadDictionary():
  return {'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}

def TestUpdateLocals():
  a = 1
  for name, value in LoadDictionary().iteritems():
    exec('%s = value' % name)
```

Of course the construction of the string statements can be automated, and the details can be hidden from the user.

Comment: Why do you even want to do this? [_The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter._](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=locals#locals)

Comment: I see. Thank you! Then how can I update the local dictionary of variables inside a function? This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place? [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: Giving a better insight of what you need will help us help you :)

Comment: For example, implementing some nice fault recovery mechanism. When a program failed and restart, it calls this function to read a dictionary from a file and update the local variables. With this, the user when writing the program can simply initialize the variables as usual and then call the update locals function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locals are not updated here because, in the first case, the variable declared has a global scope. But when declared inside a function, the variable loses scope outside it.

Thus, the original value of the locals() is not changed in the  `UpdateLocals` function.

PS: This might not be related to your question, but using camel case is not a good practice in Python. Try using the other method.

`update_locals()` instead of `UpdateLocals()`

**Edit** To answer the question in your comment:

There is something called a System Stack. The main job of this system stack during the execution of a code is to manage local variables, make sure the control returns to the correct statement after the completion of execution of the called function etc.,

So, everytime a function call is made, a new entry is created in that stack,
which contains the line number (or instruction number) to which the control has to return after the return statement, and a set of fresh local variables.

The local variables when the control is inside the function, will be taken from the stack entry. Thus, the set of locals in both the functions are not the same. The entry in the stack is popped when the control exits from the function. Thus, the changes you made inside the function are erased, unless and until those variables have a global scope.

Comment: Thank you! But I print `a` inside the function, why it still loses scope?

Comment: @shaoyl85: That is why they are called local variables. When the control goes outside the function, such a variable does not exist. By passing the `locals()` dictionary, you are just sending a dictionary with those values. But changing that does not change the original locals in the calling function

Comment: I thought when the `UpdateLocals` is called, the function `TestUpdateLocals` hasn't finished executing yet, so the "locals dictionary" is still somewhere in the memory. I could do something hacky, such as constructing some statement strings to manually pull out the values in the dictionary and use them to set the local variables, then exec this constructed statement string. It would be ugly and I don't prefer doing that.

Comment: @shaoyl85: There is something called System stack. search for it to see how function calls are executed and how the local variables are managed. When the new function is called, a stack entry is created in the system stack, and so the locals of the test_update_locals function is not the current set of locals in update_locals

Answer (score 9):

You have asked a very good question. In fact, the ability to update local variables is very important and crucial in saving and loading datasets for machine learning or in games. However, most developers of Python language have not come to a realization of its importance. They focus too much on conformity and optimization which is nevertheless important too.

**Imagine you are developing a game or running a deep neural network (DNN), if all local variables are serializable, saving the entire game or DNN can be simply put into one line as `print(locals())`, and loading the entire game or DNN can be simply put into one line as `locals().update(eval(sys.stdin.read()))`.**

Currently, `globals().update(...)` takes immediate effect but `locals().update(...)` does not work because Python documentation says:

> The default locals act as described for function locals() below:
> modifications to the default locals dictionary should not be
> attempted. Pass an explicit locals dictionary if you need to see
> effects of the code on locals after function exec() returns.

Why they design Python in such way is because of optimization and conforming the `exec` statement into a function:

> To modify the locals of a function on the fly is not possible without
> several consequences: normally, function locals are not stored in a
> dictionary, but an array, whose indices are determined at compile time
> from the known locales. This collides at least with new locals added
> by exec. The old exec statement circumvented this, because the
> compiler knew that if an exec without globals/locals args occurred in
> a function, that namespace would be "unoptimized", i.e. not using the
> locals array. Since exec() is now a normal function, the compiler does
> not know what "exec" may be bound to, and therefore can not treat is
> specially.

Since `global().update(...)` works, the following piece of code will work in root namespace (i.e., outside any function) because locals() is the same as globals() in root namespace:

```
locals().update({'a':3, 'b':4})
print(a, b)
```

But this will not work inside a function.

However, as hacker-level Python programmers, we can use `sys._getframe(1).f_locals` instead of `locals()`. From what I have tested so far, on Python 3, the following piece of code always works:

```
def f1():
  sys._getframe(1).f_locals.update({'a':3, 'b':4})
  print(a, b)

f1()
```

However, `sys._getframe(1).f_locals` does not work in root namespace.

Comment: Finally a normal answer

Comment: oui . si . yes ... and no sarcasm in the comments !! hurray

Comment: If the variable is defined locally before the call to update it does not work
```python
def f1():
  a = 1
  sys._getframe(1).f_locals.update({'a':3, 'b':4})
  print(a, b)
f1()
```
as it will print "1 4"