# Python - list to dictionary name

Tags: python-3.x

Given a list:
business = ['one','two','three']

I want to create an empty dictionary named after each element which would be populated later with data.  Note: I am not trying to create a dictionary with a key of those names but rather a dictionary named after each.  This way I can correlate the list items to dictionaries with the corresponding info.

I'm also using the configparser module to read in an ini that looks like:

```
[business]
one = regex1|regex2
two = regex1|regex2
three = 

business = `['one','two','three']
for each in business:
    each_regex = config[business][each]
    each = {}
```

I know this isn't right but it illustrates my request.  Obviously, "each" is trashed on each loop with the above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Don't do that. Instead create a dictionary of business with dictionaries for each business, so you access them like `business_dic[my_business]`. You can see the suggested duplicate for how to do what you are trying to do and reasons for not doing it.

Comment: look up collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to create variables named `one`, `two`, and `three`, based on the content of the list `business`? This is a terrible practice and definitely not recommended. If I were you, I would just make a large dictionary named `businesses` that contains `business name:data dictionary` pairs. So, something like this:

```
businesses = {
    'one': {
        'somekey': 'someval',
        'someotherkey': 'someotherval',
        },
    'two': {
        'somekey': 'someval',
        'someotherkey': 'someotherval',
        },
}
```

If you really want to assign variables dynamically, you could do something like this:

```py
for name in businesses:
    locals()[name] = {}
```

Keep in mind, this [won't work inside functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67367191/22930104). The linked answer suggests that you can do the following if you wanted it to work in functions:

```py
import sys

def terrible_idea():
    for name in businesses:
        sys._getframe(1).f_locals[name] = {}
```

Or, simply inject the variable into the global scope (i.e. available outside of the function as well):

```py
for name in businesses:
    globals()[name] = {}
```

Finally, you could also use f-strings to build up python statements and execute them with exec, like this:

```py
for name in businesses:
    exec(f"{name} = {{}}")
```

Using `exec` has the added advantage (sarcasm) that your code is now vulnerable to script injection. You can verify this by trying to register a business called `import antigravity#`.

Sit down and have a hard think about how you can re-structure your code to avoid creating variables dynamically.

Comment: Warnings and recommendations heeded.  I'll explore the dictionary of dictionary route rather than the variable dictionary names